# Fix CSS issue when changing color in Shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny

I added a `CSS` to change the color of a Shiny theme. But, I'm having a problem: The top bar that's supposed to be green is going down to the bottom. I've inserted a figure attached for you to see. Did I go wrong with something or is something else missing?

Can you help me?

Thank you very much!

I insert a executable code below.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

function.cl<-function(dt){
  df <- structure(
    list(date = c("01-08-2021","01-08-2021","01-08-2021","01-08-2021","01-08-2021",
                  "08-08-2021","08-08-2021","08-08-2021","08-08-2021","08-08-2021","08-08-2021",
                  "13-08-2021","13-08-2021","13-08-2021","13-08-2021","13-08-2021"),
         Week= c("Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday",
                 "Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Friday","Friday","Friday","Friday","Friday"),
         D1 = c(0,1,0,0,5,0,1,0,0,9,4,3,4,5,6,7), DR01 = c(2,1,0,0,3,0,1,0,1,7,2,3,4,6,7,8),
         DR02 = c(2,0,0,0,4,2,1,0,1,4,2,3,4,5,6,7),  DR03 = c(2,0,0,2,6,2,0,0,1,5,2,2,4,5,7,5),
         DR04 = c(2,0,0,5,6,2,0,0,3,7,2,3,4,5,6,4),  DR05 = c(2,0,0,5,6,2,0,0,7,7,2,3,4,5,6,7),
         DR06 = c(2,0,0,5,7,2,0,0,7,7,1,3,5,6,7,8),  DR07 = c(2,0,0,6,9,2,0,0,7,8,1,3,5,6,4,3)),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
  
  df$date <- parse_date_time(df$date, c('ymd', 'dmy'))
  
  scatter_date <- function(dt, dta = df) {
    dta %>%
      filter(date == ymd(dt)) %>%
      summarize(across(starts_with("DR"), sum)) %>%
      pivot_longer(everything(), names_pattern = "DR(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
      mutate(name = as.numeric(name)) %>%
      plot(xlab = "Days", ylab = "Types", xlim = c(0, 7))
  }  
  Plot1<-scatter_date(dt)
  
  return(list(
    "Plot1" = Plot1, 
    date = df$date
  ))
}


  ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                          br(),
                         
                          tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.navbar-static-top {background-color: green;}',
                                                    '.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a {background-color: green;}')),
                          tabPanel("",
                                   sidebarLayout(
                                     sidebarPanel(
                                       
                                       uiOutput("date"),
                                       br(),
                                     ),
                                     
                                     mainPanel(
                                       tabsetPanel(
                                         tabPanel("",plotOutput("Graph",width = "95%", height = "600")))),
                                     ))
                          ))


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  data <- reactive(function.cl("2021-08-01"))
  
  output$date <- renderUI({
    all_dates <- seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-01-15'), by = "day")
    disabled <- as.Date(setdiff(all_dates, as.Date(data()$date)), origin = "1970-01-01")
    dateInput(input = "date", 
              label = "Select Date",
              min = min(data()$date),
              max = max(data()$date),
              value = max(data()$date),
              format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
              datesdisabled = disabled)
  })
  
  output$Graph <- renderPlot({
    req(input$date)
    function.cl(input$date)[["Plot1"]]
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have wrong `)` in your UI code. It turns out all your UI code is wrapped inside that `tags$head` section. Try to indent your code better and you will find out the problem in the future.

Now use this:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

function.cl<-function(dt){
    df <- structure(
        list(date = c("01-08-2021","01-08-2021","01-08-2021","01-08-2021","01-08-2021",
                      "08-08-2021","08-08-2021","08-08-2021","08-08-2021","08-08-2021","08-08-2021",
                      "13-08-2021","13-08-2021","13-08-2021","13-08-2021","13-08-2021"),
             Week= c("Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday",
                     "Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Friday","Friday","Friday","Friday","Friday"),
             D1 = c(0,1,0,0,5,0,1,0,0,9,4,3,4,5,6,7), DR01 = c(2,1,0,0,3,0,1,0,1,7,2,3,4,6,7,8),
             DR02 = c(2,0,0,0,4,2,1,0,1,4,2,3,4,5,6,7),  DR03 = c(2,0,0,2,6,2,0,0,1,5,2,2,4,5,7,5),
             DR04 = c(2,0,0,5,6,2,0,0,3,7,2,3,4,5,6,4),  DR05 = c(2,0,0,5,6,2,0,0,7,7,2,3,4,5,6,7),
             DR06 = c(2,0,0,5,7,2,0,0,7,7,1,3,5,6,7,8),  DR07 = c(2,0,0,6,9,2,0,0,7,8,1,3,5,6,4,3)),
        class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
    
    df$date <- parse_date_time(df$date, c('ymd', 'dmy'))
    
    scatter_date <- function(dt, dta = df) {
        dta %>%
            filter(date == ymd(dt)) %>%
            summarize(across(starts_with("DR"), sum)) %>%
            pivot_longer(everything(), names_pattern = "DR(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
            mutate(name = as.numeric(name)) %>%
            plot(xlab = "Days", ylab = "Types", xlim = c(0, 7))
    }  
    Plot1<-scatter_date(dt)
    
    return(list(
        "Plot1" = Plot1, 
        date = df$date
    ))
}


ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE, selected = "abc",
                        tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.navbar-static-top {background-color: green;}
                                                  .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a {background-color: green;}'))),
                        tabPanel("abc",
                                 sidebarLayout(
                                     sidebarPanel(
                                         uiOutput("date"),
                                         
                                         br(),
                                     ),
                                     
                                     mainPanel(
                                         tabsetPanel(
                                             tabPanel("",plotOutput("Graph",width = "95%", height = "600"))
                                         )
                                    ),
                                 )
                        )
)


server <- function(input, output,session) {
    data <- reactive(function.cl("2021-08-01"))
    
    output$date <- renderUI({
        all_dates <- seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-01-15'), by = "day")
        disabled <- as.Date(setdiff(all_dates, as.Date(data()$date)), origin = "1970-01-01")
        dateInput(input = "date", 
                  label = "Select Date",
                  min = min(data()$date),
                  max = max(data()$date),
                  value = max(data()$date),
                  format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
                  datesdisabled = disabled)
    })
    
    output$Graph <- renderPlot({
        req(input$date)
        function.cl(input$date)[["Plot1"]]
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks lz100. Just a question if I have two tabPanel, what would the selected part look like? For exemple, you insert `selected = "abc"`, what if by chance there was one more?

Comment: You can specify which one to be the selected, see if you choose `selected = "second"`, then on app start, the second panel will be displayed by default and `abc` will be hidden.